# AWS SAM Rust - Deploy multiple lambda functions from same crate

Tags: amazon-web-services, rust, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I'm trying to deploy a basic serverless application that contains two Rust lambda functions. I'm using SAM to deploy the application.

**The issue is how to get SAM to pick up the correct "bootstrap" file.** Because both functions are built in the same `CodeUri` path, SAM does not execute both the Make commands. Instead, it just copies the output of Function1 to Function2 (this seems like a design flaw in SAM?). Thus, both lambdas currently get deployed with the same code.

My build directory is

```
myapp/
- src/
  - bin/
    - function1.rs   (note: function1 & 2 depend on lib.rs)
    - function2.rs
  - lib.rs
- Cargo.toml
- Makefile
- template.yaml
```

The template.yaml file:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Globals:
  Function:
    Handler: bootstrap.is.the.handler
    Runtime: provided.al2
    Architectures:
      - x86_64

Resources:
  Function1:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: .
  
  Function2:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: .
```

The Makefile is:

```
build-Function1:
    cargo lambda build
    cp ./target/lambda/function1/bootstrap $(ARTIFACTS_DIR)

build-Function2: # This never gets run!
    cargo lambda build
    cp ./target/lambda/function2/bootstrap $(ARTIFACTS_DIR)
```

Commands to build/deploy

```
sam build
sam deploy
```

I'm open to other build structures. I've also tried structuring the project using rust workspaces. But, because SAM copies the build source to a separate directory, I cannot find a way to add module dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much struggle, I have come up with a hacky solution, that I'm sure cannot be the recommended way.

1. Use rust workspaces, so the folder structure is:

```
root/
  common/
    lib.rs
    Cargo.toml
  function1/
    main.rs
    Cargo.toml
    Makefile
  function2/
    main.rs
    Cargo.toml
    Makefile
  Cargo.toml
  template.yaml
```

root/Cargo.toml:

```
[workspace]
members = [
  "common"
  "function1",
  "function2",
]
```

2. Set `template.yaml` file to use different `codeURIs`:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Globals:
  Function:
    Handler: bootstrap.is.the.handler
    Runtime: provided.al2
    Architectures:
      - x86_64

Resources:
  Function1:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: function1
  
  Function2:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: function2
```

3. (The hack step) In each Makefile, `cp` back into the source dir so it builds with all the source. (This has added benefit of sharing the build cache between targets)

```
build-Function1:
    cd $(PWD); cargo lambda build --release
    cp $(PWD)/target/lambda/function1/bootstrap $(ARTIFACTS_DIR)
```

This solution is compatible with `cargo lambda watch` and `sam build`/`sam deploy` commands.

Binary size is large since all lambdas duplicate the base library. I'm uncertain if this is avoidable with Rust.

I'm yet to trial it with deployment from CI servers.